# Chrome download error when downloading file with Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

I have an application that shows a page, the user clicks on a button, and downloads a CSV file. I want to run this with Puppeteer.

Problem is that the CSV is downloaded empty and with an error. This happens both with `headless` true and false. The page finished loading, and I increased the timeout, but it still fails. What could be the issue?

[image]

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
    
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
       headless: false
    });

    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('http://localhost:4400/login', { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });    
    
    await page._client.send('Page.setDownloadBehavior', {
        behavior: 'allow',
        downloadPath: './',
    });

    await page.waitForSelector('#run-and-export');
    await page.click('#run-and-export');
  
    // file-downloaded is turned on when the file finished downloading (not to close the window)
    await page.waitForSelector('#file-downloaded', { timeout: 120000 }); 

    await browser.close();
    
})();
```

The code in the application that generates the file to download is an Angular service:

```
@Injectable({ 
    providedIn: 'root' 
})
export class DownloadService {

    downloadFile(content:any, fileName: string, mimeType: string){
    
        var blob = new Blob([(content)], {type: mimeType});
        var a = document.createElement('a');
        a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        a.download = fileName;
        a.click();

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the `userDataDir` when launching the browser?

Comment: I just tried, I got the same error: `const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
       headless: false,
    userDataDir: './myUserDataDir'
    });`

Comment: You're throwing away all errors that might contain a clue as to what's going on. Make sure to attach a `catch` to the main async function.

Comment: I wrapped the main async function as `f()` and added `f().catch((error) => console.log('there\'s an error=' + error))` and nothing is printed

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is what made this work:

```
const downloadPath = path.resolve('/my/path');

await page._client.send('Page.setDownloadBehavior', {
    behavior: 'allow',
    downloadPath: downloadPath 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem, the download failed, in the download dir I got `filename.pdf.crdownload` and no other file.

The download dir is up two levels from the app dir `../../download_dir`

The solution was (as suggested by ps0604) :

```
const path = require('path');
const download_path = path.resolve('../../download_dir/');

await page._client.send('Page.setDownloadBehavior', {
    behavior: 'allow',
    userDataDir: './',
    downloadPath: download_path,
});
```

If someone is searching for `.crdownload` file and download error.